# How to solve "Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException"?

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, nullpointerexception, processing

I am currently doing a port over of codes from Processing to Netbeans. However, I have met with some difficulties as the exact same codes running in processing gave me a Null Pointer Exception when I run it in Netbeans java.
The errors I'm faced with are these:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at gardeningmania.GardeningMania.loadPng(GardeningMania.java:303)  
at gardeningmania.GardeningMania.setupThreading(GardeningMania.java:315)  
at gardeningmania.GardeningMania.setup(GardeningMania.java:182)   
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2281)
at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:243)
at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

These are some parts of the codes that resulted in the above state error:

```
@Override

public void setup() {
    setupThreading("/Menus/", menuLoader, menuThread);
    setupThreading("/Navigations/", navLoader, navThread);
    setupThreading("/Navigations2/", nav2Loader, nav2Thread);
}

void loadPng(File[] files, ImageLoader loader) {

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        String path = files[i].getAbsolutePath();
        if (path.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")) {
            loader.loadImg(path);
        }
    }
}

void setupThreading(String folderName, ImageLoader loader, Thread threading) {

    File dir = new File(sketchPath + folderName);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    threading = new Thread(loader);
    loadPng(files, loader);
    threading.start();
}
```

Any idea how I can go about solving these errors?

Comment: please **Use format in a proper way**

Comment: Make whatever is on line 303 not-null.

Comment: Either `menuLoader` or `navLoader` or `nav2Loader` is null

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are pointing to the right directory and its not a relative path. I feel the following code is giving a null object `files`:

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
```

Comment: maybe empty but not null

Comment: The problem is you're guessing as there's no way to answer the OP's question authoritatively. You may be correct, but it's equally as plausible that his `loader` variable is `null`

Comment: @user2310289 `File.listFiles()` will return `null` if the path is wrong

Comment: @BrianRoach : Exactly that is what I am guessing. The user said it worked on another environment. As relative path is used, the system is unable to find the folder when he/she shifted to Netbeans

Comment: Sorry, should clean my glasses `If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this method returns null.`

Comment: @GV Apparently my glasses need cleaning as well, I missed that in the Q. I withdraw my comment :-D

Comment: Luckily, I don't wear glasses :-)

Answer (score 0):

Either menuLoader or navLoader or nav2Loader is null

Or as @GV has probably correctly guessed the filePath on your new environment is incorrect, therefore resulting in `File.ListFiles()` returning `null`

Comment: You two need to combine your answers ... *then* you've covered the bases.